# How to install an external python package in ROS2?

Tags: ros2, python

I use pointpillars for object detection on pointcloud data (https://github.com/shangjie-li/pointpillars/tree/master). I have successfully trained and tested the deep network (Conda environment, Python 3.7, numpy 1.21.6). The pointpillars folder is located outside of ROS2 package and all python codes in pointpillars folder are non-ROS modules.
I would like to run the deep learning code (execute `test.py` and `demo.py`) in a Ros2 node (Ubuntu 22.04, Ros2 Humble, Python 3.10.12). I created a Ros2 python subscriber (`pc_subscriber.py`, `setup.py`, `package.xml`). For some reason, I have removed all imported python modules from `test.py` and `demo.py` (pointpillars folder) and put them in `pc_subscriber.py` (code below between two hash lines). However, it seems the Ros node can not import these python modules located in pointpillars folder and I get error (for example :

```
from . import iou3d_nms_cuda
ImportError: cannot import name 'iou3d_nms_cuda' from 'ops.iou3d_nms' (unknown location)
```

). Generally, I do not know how to install all codes in pointpillars folder as python modules in ROS2. Also, how to modify `pc_subscriber.py`, `setup.py`, and `package.xml` in this regard. How can I solve this issue?

I appreciate any help in advance.

Thanks,

Abbas

pc_subscriber.py

```
import rclpy
from rclpy.qos import QoSProfile, QoSReliabilityPolicy, QoSHistoryPolicy
import sensor_msgs_py.point_cloud2 as pc2
import struct

from sensor_msgs.msg import PointCloud2, PointField
import numpy as np
import open3d as o3d
import ctypes

import shutil
import numpy as np
import glob
import os
import subprocess
from subprocess import call

import argparse
import datetime
import glob
import os
import re
import time
from pathlib import Path

import numpy as np
import torch
from tensorboardX import SummaryWriter
###############################################################################
# from data import cfg, cfg_from_list, cfg_from_yaml_file, log_config_to_file
# from data import build_dataloader
# from utils import common_utils
# from utils import eval_utils
# from data import KittiDataset
# from pointpillar import build_network, load_data_to_gpu
###############################################################################
source_folder = r'/home/abbas/pointpillars-master1/Bin_data/'
destination_folder = r'/home/abbas/pointpillars-master1/data/kitti/training/velodyne/'

source_pd_labels= r'/home/abbas/pointpillars-master1/output/eval/epoch_150/val/final_result/data/'
destination_pd_labels= r'/home/abbas/pointpillars-master1/Predicted_labels/'

j=0

def callback(msg):

# Save pointclou data as bin files
    global j
    xyz_intensity = []

    gen = pc2.read_points(msg, field_names=("x", "y", "z", "intensity"), skip_nans=True)
    int_data = list(gen)

    for x in int_data:
        # Extract x, y, z, intensity values
        point = [x[0], x[1], x[2], x[3]]
        xyz_intensity.append(point)

    # Convert to NumPy array
    xyz_intensity = np.array(xyz_intensity, dtype=np.float32)

    # Save as BIN file
    bin_file_name = "/home/abbas/pointpillars-master1/Bin_data/{:06d}.bin".format(j)
    with open(bin_file_name, "wb") as bin_file:
        for point in xyz_intensity:
        # Pack x, y, z, intensity values into binary format
            packed_data = struct.pack('ffff', *point)
            bin_file.write(packed_data)  
       
    #Copy the bin files to velodyn folder for prediction     
    source = bin_file_name
    destination = destination_folder + '000001.bin'
    if os.path.isfile(source):
        shutil.copy(source, destination)
    
    #Predict the labels and save them (inference)  
    exec(open('test.py').read())

    #save the predicted labels
    sourceLabel = source_pd_labels +'000001.txt'
    destinationLabel = "/home/abbas/pointpillars-master1/Predicted_labels/{:06d}.txt".format(j)
    if os.path.isfile(sourceLabel):
        shutil.copy(sourceLabel, destinationLabel)
              
    # show the detected objects (demo)    
    exec(open('demo.py').read()) 
     
    j += 1  # Increment j for the next file
     
   
def main(args=None):
    rclpy.init(args=args)

    node = rclpy.create_node('bin_converter')
    qos_profile = QoSProfile(
            reliability=QoSReliabilityPolicy.RMW_QOS_POLICY_RELIABILITY_BEST_EFFORT,
            history=QoSHistoryPolicy.RMW_QOS_POLICY_HISTORY_KEEP_LAST,
            depth=1
        )
    subscription = node.create_subscription(
        PointCloud2,
        #'/ouster_front/points',
        '/ouster_front/filtered_obstacle_points',
        callback,
        qos_profile=qos_profile
    )
    subscription  # Prevent unused variable warning

    print("Listening for PointCloud2 messages...")
    try:
        rclpy.spin(node)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass

    node.destroy_node()
    rclpy.shutdown()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

setup.py

```
from setuptools import find_packages, setup

package_name = 'dl_bd'    

setup(
    name=package_name,
    version='0.0.0',
    packages=find_packages(exclude=['test']),
    data_files=[            ('share/ament_index/resource_index/packages',
            ['resource/' + package_name]),
        ('share/' + package_name, ['package.xml']),
    ],
    install_requires=['setuptools'],
    zip_safe=True,
    maintainer='abbas',
    maintainer_email='ToDo',
    description='Deep learning node for 3d object detection',
    license='Apache License 2.0',
    tests_require=['pytest'],
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
               'listener = dl_bd.pc_subscriber:main', 
        ],
    },
)
```

package.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-model href="http://download.ros.org/schema/package_format3.xsd" schematypens="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"?>
<package format="3">
  <name>dl_bd</name>
  <version>0.0.0</version>
  <description>Deep learning node for 3d object detection</description>
  <maintainer email="ToDo">abbas</maintainer>
  <license>Apache License 2.0</license>
  
  <depend>ros2cli</depend>
  <exec_depend>ament_index_python</exec_depend>
  <exec_depend>python3-empy</exec_depend>
  <exec_depend>python3-pkg-resources</exec_depend>
  
  <exec_depend>rclpy</exec_depend>
  <exec_depend>sensor_msgs</exec_depend>
  <exec_depend>sensor_msgs_py</exec_depend>
  <exec_depend>tensorboardX</exec_depend>

  <test_depend>ament_copyright</test_depend>
  <test_depend>ament_flake8</test_depend>
  <test_depend>ament_pep257</test_depend>
  <test_depend>python3-pytest</test_depend>

  <export>
    <build_type>ament_python</build_type>
  </export>
</package>
```